# Searching a word on all fields of an index with solr 8.9

Tags: indexing, solr

I'm fetching some datas from a sql database using the DIH of Solr. I created a field all as this :

and I would like to be able to use it to search on all fields thought it. so like if I do he query "John" it would match with a title and a author name.
Actually I have a problem, when I do a query on the all field it only works on a perfect match.
For exemple,  if I search name:lub it returns

```
        "name":"CR2/LUB/ Lub oil pump",
        "all":["1706443412665794562",
          "2165C92A-D107-48A6-A410-08D92AA77517",
          "CR2/BER/CRACK/LUB/OT/10-PU-200C",
          "CR2/LUB/ Lub oil pump"],
```

Which is good

But if I search all:lub the response show :
`"numFound":0,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs`.
The ultimate goal being to be able to use a word to search on all fields, and to ponderate the weight of the different fields.
Like, if someone search John for books it finds it in the title , and in the author fields (by looking in the all) and then ponderate, by making the title more important and viewing in the response the score of each document

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: What is the definition of the field `all`? How that field can be queried depends on how the field has been defined.

Comment: There is usually a `_text_` field defined in a default Solr core that might do what you need. But you will need to manually populate it by adding a copyField directive to your configuration.

Comment: An alternate option to search in all fields in to use edismax query parser.

Comment: Thanks for the comments I realised that my all field was a string type, changing it to a text general allowed me to do the search on all fields like I wanted. But I still have question about how to  weight a specific column, do I open a new question?

Comment: Yes, a new question would be good.